# How do I visualize XYZ+Field volume data, stored in a simple table, in Paraview?

Tags: 3d, grid, visualization, paraview

For rather long time I've used to work in Goldensoftware Surfer/Voxler. In this programs it's very easy to visualise table data. The scheme looks like this: data input (on this step I can specify x, y, z and a component - some physical field data)->gridding->contour/volume visualisation. But I can't find any clue how load data from table and then grid it in some way and then make a contour/volume render in Paraview.
For example, I have a table:

```
X       Y       Z       Rho
-135.25 185.25  282.84  2284.442
-135.25 114.75  282.84  954.951
-100    100     282.84  6825.375
-64.75  114.75  282.84  3640.483
-50     150     282.84  3745.877
...
14.75   35.25   400.00  2822.855
14.75   -35.25  400.00  6876.960
50      -50     400.00  1375.617
```

How can I make a regular 3D grid (for sake of definiteness by kriging method) of this data? And how can I then make a contour/volume render?

Answer (score 5):

The first step is reading your data into ParaView. ParaView can read in delimited text files as tables, which is essentially what you have. Assuming your data is in a .txt file, you can directly open the data. By default, the reader assumes that you have a comma delimiter (i.e. a csv file), but you can change it. In the properties panel after you have opened the file, change the `Field Delimiter Characters` from a comma to a space. Also, check the box next to `Merge Consecutive Delimiters`.

The data are loaded in a table structure, and ParaView will initially show it in a spreadsheet view. You can convert it to a 3D grid with one of a pair of filters. The first filter is `Table To Points`. You just select the x, y, and z columns and it will generate a set of discrete points in space. The second filter is `Table To Structured Grid`. In this filter you specify both the x, y, and z columns as well as the extent of a grid. It will then build a curvilinear grid of points based on the rows of data in the table.