# Adding points in a mesh by using Paraview

Tags: csv, mesh, paraview

I try to plot some points (with (x,y,z) coordinates) in a mesh that I visualize with Paraview. I listed the points in a .csv file but I can't find how to show them on the mesh. 
Do you have an answer for that?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the Table To Points filter?

Comment: Have a look to this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510129/how-do-i-visualize-xyzfield-volume-data-stored-in-a-simple-table-in-paraview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I visualize XYZ+Field volume data, stored in a simple table, in Paraview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510129/how-do-i-visualize-xyzfield-volume-data-stored-in-a-simple-table-in-paraview)